# Qt connect toPlainText() to different class

Tags: c++, qt

toPlainText() returns a QString, and connecting slots/signals requires void returns. When I'm working within the same class as the textEdit, I can just do something like this,

```
QString Transition::getSkipIndex(){
    skipIndex= Transition::ui ->skipEdit->toPlainText();
    return skipIndex;
```

Which can easily be applied to any other method in the `Transition` class. Since I'm going between classes, I obviously need to use slots and signals, but I am stuck as to how to proceed. I'm very new to Qt, and don't fully understand slots and signals yet, so guidance would be appreciated.

Also, the other class is in its own thread, otherwise I could just do a simple function call.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want plainText of TextEdit in another classes? Why do you need signals? Gust do this method public and every class can get plainText.

Comment: @Chernobyl That method is public in `Transition`. How would I call it from another class?

Comment: @Chernobyl you seem to have removed your answer. Does this mean I should go with Erik's?

Comment: When I wrote my answer I didn't know about another thread, so my answer is not correct. Wrong answers should be deleted or improved. I can't improve this, so I deleted it. Sorry, but I can't help you unfortunately.

Comment: @Chernobyl Alright just wanted to be sure. Thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass your `QString` to another class using signals/slots you can do something like the example below. Note that this is obviously just a dummy example to show how you could 'emit' a signal from a class in a method and have another class receive that signal and have its slot receive the (in this example) `QString`. I cannot comment whether this is the best approach or whether what Chernobyl is asking is the way to go.

**emitter.h**

```
#ifndef EMITTER_H
#define EMITTER_H

#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QString>

class Emitter: public QObject
{

 Q_OBJECT
 public:
   Emitter() { edit.setText("My Text");  }
   void emitText() { emit textChange(edit.toPlainText()); }
 signals:
   void textChange(const QString&);

 private:
  QTextEdit edit;

};

#endif
```

**receiver.h**

```
#ifndef RECEIVER_H
#define RECEIVER_H

#include <QtCore>



class Receiver: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public slots:
  void receiveText(const QString& text ) { qDebug() << "Recevied Text" << text; }
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "emitter.h"
#include "receiver.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc,argv);

  Emitter emitter;
  Receiver recevier;

  QObject::connect( &emitter, SIGNAL( textChange(const QString&) ) , &recevier, SLOT( receiveText(const QString& )));
  emitter.emitText();

  return app.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is asked for. But note that you don't need signal/slot for normal function calls, also if objects of different classes and member funtions or if QString is  involved. This is normal C++, just call the other function.

Comment: One aspect I forgot to mention: the other function is in its own thread, which complicates things. I'm editing the main post to reflect that